# Async in command handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Async will not work in my command handler in discord.js, does anyone know where my error is?

```
 execute(message, args, Discord, async)
 ----------In index--------
 else if (command === 'embed'){
      client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord, async)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass `async` as a parameter. That's not how it works. `async` keyword enables asynchronous, promise-based behavior. So to make a function asynchronous, you need to use the keyword `async` before the function. In your case, its `async execute(message,args,Discord)`. You clearly need to learn about [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).